# Event listeners not added in ngAfterViewChecked

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, drag-and-drop, addeventlistener

I writing some code to enable drag-and-drop functionality on some widgets (just some specific divs), the code is writing inside an angular component which implements a medium-editor, while initialized, we instantiate a serie of widget builders.

To make a long story short, I am noticing that once I add one widget (called gallery), it causes issues in adding the event listener allowing the drag-&-drop on the rest of the widget. Said widget (gallery) is slow to initialized, it needs some async execution before fully constructing on DOM-tree.

```
// We use this step in the life-cycle hook because we're trying to wait as much as possible for DOM-tree to fully generate.
// otherwise, some DOM-selector-calls fail because their targeted elements are not available just yet.
ngAfterViewChecked(): void {

    // This method adds the drag/drop event listeners to the safe/sync widgets.
    // never mind the processing inside, it just makes sure to enable dragging and dropping.
    const syncWidgetsEventListenersAdding = (element) => {
        element.addEventListener('dragstart', (event: any) => {
            // @ts-ignore
            document.dragSourceElement = element
            event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move'
            event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'move'
            event.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', element.outerHTML)
        })
        element.addEventListener('dragover', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
        })
        element.addEventListener('mouseover', (_) => {
            element.classList.add('draggable-cursor')
        })
        element.addEventListener('dragend', (_) => {
            // @ts-ignore
            element.previousElementSibling.style.borderBottom = ''
        })
    }
    
    // Alright, here, find widget to be make draggable with marker-class 'draggableWidget'
    // Note that Gallery widget isn't market with this class, because we've said fuck it let's exclude it if we can't make it work
    const draggingLogic = () => {
        document.querySelectorAll('.draggableWidget').forEach((element) => {
            syncWidgetsEventListenersAdding(element)
        })
        // Some more drag/drop logic, never mind the following.
        // @ts-ignore
        document
            .querySelector('medium-editor')
            .querySelectorAll('p')
            .forEach((pTagElement) => {
                pTagElement.setAttribute('draggable', 'true')
                pTagElement.addEventListener('dragover', (event) => {
                    event.preventDefault()
                })
                pTagElement.addEventListener('drop', (_) => {
                    // @ts-ignore
                    if (document.dragSourceElement && document.dragSourceElement !== pTagElement) {
                        // @ts-ignore
                        pTagElement.after(document.dragSourceElement)
                    }

                    return false
                })
                pTagElement.addEventListener('dragenter', (_) => {
                    pTagElement.style.borderBottom = '3px dashed #85bc31'
                })
                pTagElement.addEventListener('dragleave', (_) => {
                    pTagElement.style.borderBottom = ''
                })
                pTagElement.addEventListener('dragend', (_) => {})
            })
    }

    // Since all of the above was inside a ngAfterViewChecked, we're making sure the preceding function only
    // execute when necessary, a.k.a when either a new widget is added or on page loading. Otherwise, memory leak will be crippling.
    const numberOfWidgets = document.querySelectorAll('.draggableWidget').length

    if (numberOfWidgets === 0) {
        this.beforeHowManyWidgets = 0
    } else {
        if (numberOfWidgets > this.beforeHowManyWidgets) {
            this.beforeHowManyWidgets = numberOfWidgets
            draggingLogic()
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the issue: when gallery is added, even if the querySelectorAll does not target it (because the gallery widget does not have the class .draggableWidget), the rest of the widget only get part of the bargened listeners:

[image]

For example in the image 'dragstart' is added but not 'dragend'.

We take gallery off, all goes back to norm.

What should I understand here? Outside of programmatically verifying that widgets have received all listeners, how could I debug this to make sure where the chain breaks?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: why not use @angular/cdk/drag-drop? -it's not related with material else with `@angular/cdk`-. You can also use template reference variables and ViewChildren and subscribe to the query.changes

Comment: @Eliseo: could do, but I was trying to understand why the problem of unadded event listener occurs first. As for ViewChildren, the issue will be that we don't have the widgets in advance, they are dynamically added by the users.

Comment: It's the reason to use `this.variableViewChildren.changes.subscribe(res=>{..})` see the [doc](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList#properties). Inside subscribe you has the elements yet. I'm prety sure that the problem is that the elements are not yet in ngAfterViewChecked

Comment: @Eliseo: ok, these indications sound interesting, I will give it a try and let you know; in the meantime, you can - if you so desire - post an answer so I could upvote it and eventually accept it; thanks !